# Crashlytics on the internal network

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

I want to use Crashlytics on iOS on the internal network, without Internet access, which ones do I need to open ports or give access to the resource so that everything works?

Comment: this is not possible. of course you need internet access to talk to fabric servers.

Comment: may be can i give access to http://fabric.io ??

Comment: Crashlytics is not open source so that you could host it on your own servers. As for logs with internet network, Crashlytics will retain the logs and transmit them to their server once your app opens in internet capable environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To support a blocked traffic device to access Fabric & Crashlytics, you can whitelist the following domains on ports 80 and 443:

*.fabric.io

*.crashlytics.com